# How to use one EditText to set the text of multiple TextViews in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I have four `TextView` items, all of which are clickable. I also have one `EditText` item and one "Go" button. The text input into the `EditText` field by the user must be used to set the text of that `TextView` item which was clicked.

So if I click `TextView`  item number 2 and then input some text into the `EditText` box and then hit the "Go" button, the text input must be written in `TextView` item number 2 only and the other 3 `TextView` items should be left unchanged. 
How do I accomplish this?  Inside the "Go" button's onClick method, how do I find out which `TextView` was clicked?

Comment: keep track of which text view was clicked say you have 0 to 3 .. When the second textview is clicked store 1, and then when go is pressed , use a switch case and set the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single int variable in the class

set onclick listener for all the text view and set the id to the variable and use it in the button click.

here i a example that i tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView t1, t2, t3;
EditText e1;
Button b1;
private static int ids = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    t1.setOnClickListener(this);
    t2.setOnClickListener(this);
    t3.setOnClickListener(this);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ids != 0) {
                TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(ids);
                tx.setText(e1.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.textView1:
    case R.id.textView2:
    case R.id.textView3:
        ids = v.getId();
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you please tell me why must we use the switch in the onClick method? Why not do it the way LeMoN.xaH has done?

Comment: in that place u can use that also but there exists some cases. if there exists any other view other than text view how it will behave. if there exists an image view and if he wanted to set onclick listener for that too in that case he has to do this switch case . thats y i always use like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Create four *non-local* variables ( say *int*), one for each textview and initialize it to **zero**. When you click a textview, set the *corresponding* variable to a non-zero value, in the *onclick event of that textview*.

Finally, when you type in edittext and click go, check which textview variable is **non-zero**, and change that textview accordingly ( in the onClick event of *go*). Also remember to set that textview variable *back to zero* so that the logic will work for future inputs.

**EDIT**: You can also simplify this method by making use of a **single** variable and store 1,2,3,4 etc here. But the **advantage** of the method I suggested is that it would work *even if* you want to set the text of *more than one* but not *all* textviews when go is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have these four textviews:

```
TextView1
TextView2
TextView3
TextView4
```

Specify the `onClick()` attribute of these TextViews in xml itself with the value of, say, `selectedTextView`, as below:

```
<TextView
...
android:onClick="selectedTextView"
/>
```

Now, inside your activity,

take a global String variable as,

```
TextView mTextView;
```

Then, create a method outside `onCreate()` named,

```
public void selectedTextView(View view)
{
    mTextView = (TextView) view;
}
```

And inside onClick of button `Go`, simply set the text using:

```
mTextView.setText("Your value inside EditText goes here");
```

Comment: android:onClick="selectedTextView" will only work if you are using an activity it doesn't work with fragments unless the onClick method for that fragment lives in the activity the fragment belongs too but that is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Find each `Textview` in Your Activity class like :

```
    TextView tv_1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
    TextView tv_2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
    TextView tv_3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_3);
    TextView tv_4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_4);
```

Get value from the second Textview with onclick function using

```
String value=tv_2.getText().tostring();
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont like the setting of an ID to know which textView to set. We are working on an Object Oriented Language why then use strutured data. why not just do something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView textView = null;
    EditText e1;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4)).setOnClickListener(this);
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editText != null) {
                    editText.setText(e1.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      editText = (TextView)v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare one **integer** to keep track of the textview which was clicked and then in onclicklistener of button you should check that integer value and according to that value set the text of particular  **textview** which was clicked.I just created demo code which gives you the idea enough to get you on path..:)

### Solution:--

```
    int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

    Button btnGo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 0;
        }
    });
    tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 1;
        }
    });
    tv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 2;
        }
    });
    tv4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = 3;
        }
    });

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tv1.setText(et.getText().toString());
                break;

            case 1:
                tv2.setText(et.getText().toString());
                break;

            case 2:
                tv3.setText(et.getText().toString());
                break;

            case 3:
                tv4.setText(et.getText().toString());
                break;

            }
        }
    });

}
```